# View the file from base64 string instead of varbinary

Tags: javascript, sql, asp.net, base64, varbinary

This is my simple program on downloading file from a varbinary string on click.

Controller:

```
  public ActionResult Download(string StudentID, string SQNC)
      {
         string query = "exec spToGetVarbinaryString'" + StudentID + "','" + SQNC + "' ";
         string dataStr = GlobalFunction.DataTableToJSON(GlobalFunction.TableFromMSSQL(dbname, query));
         dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(dataStr);
         byte[] file = data[0].ImgVarbinary;

         return File(file, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, (string)data[0].FileName);
      }
```

how I download the File:

```
<a type="button" href="ControllerName/Download?StudentID=${row.StudentID}&SQNC=${row.SQNC}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm active" role="button" aria-pressed="true">View File</a>
```

Now, I want the file instead of being downloaded on click, It will appear on tab or new. I tried the method of converting my Varbinary to Base64 string, but it doesnt read the PDF file for this example below.

From VarBinary to Base64 in SQL

```
    update a set a.ImgStr=baze64
    from #mytemptable
    cross apply (select ImgVarbinary as '*' for xml path('')) T (baze64)
    where a.ImgVarbinary is not null
```

Displaying Base64 PDF File (Display doesn't work)

```
<iframe width="500" height="500"
            src="data:application/pdf;base64,<base64stringhere>"
```

I found a sample base64 data in this [JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/eqc3umab/), I tried it on local and it works.

Image example (left one: my base64 string. Right one: base64 from the js fiddle)
[image]

How can I do this and why my base64 string isn't working well? Thanks for answering.

Comment: You cannot force a download on a new tab. It is up to the client.

Comment: @KJ yes, my base64file starts with JVBER like from the example. But I noticed that the base64 string was not long compared to the base64 sample from the JSFiddle, is that the reason why it isn't working or I'm doing my conversion wrong?

Comment: @VDWWD hello, yes so instead I want the file to open in new tab. So I tried to convert it into base64 string, but it doesn't working. Is there any way to do it in my example?

Answer (score 0):

add something like this on click event to read bytes....

```cs
public class LoadPdfFileHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public bool IsResuable => false;
    
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string id = context.Request.QueryString["id"];
        // TODO: Verify that the user is allowed to view the specified record.
        
        using (var connection = new MySqlConnection("..."))
        using (var command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT Data, ContentType FROM SomeTable WHERE ID = @ID", connection))
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);
            
            connection.Open();
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
            {
                if (!reader.Read())
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
                    return;
                }

                string contentType = (string)dr["ContentType"];
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentType)) contentType = "application/octet-stream";
                context.Response.ContentType = contentType;
                
                byte[] bytes = (byte[])dr["Data"];
                context.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then Write Frame Using this...

```js
myiframe.Attributes["src"] = ResolveUrl("~/loadPdfFile.ashx?id=" + idOfTheRecordToLoad);
```

You can check Other Reference [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/5261184/How-to-open-pdf-in-iframe-from-binary-data-in-form) [image reference](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Convert-Base64-string-to-Byte-Array-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)